# Array Filter returning same element

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to move questions up and down an array,so i update the sequence number in the object and sort them based on it.But the following filter statements keeps returning the same element even if the array contains the desired values.

Will modifying the objects like this update them in the original array  ?

```
var questiontoswap = this.questions.filter(x => x.sequence == question.sequence + 1 && ("state" in x) ? (x.state != 3) : true)[0];
var originalquestion = this.questions.filter(x => x.sequence == question.sequence && ("state" in x) ? (x.state != 3) : true
                            )[0];
questiontoswap.sequence -= 1;
originalquestion.sequence += 1;
let filteredquestions =this.questions.filter(x => x.state != 3).sort((a, b) => (a.sequence < b.sequence ? -1 : 1));
```

**Array**

```
questions: (3) […]
​​​
0: {…}
​​​​
questionId: 7
​​​​
questionLanguages: (4) […]
​​​​
questionType: "Short answer"
​​​​
questionTypeId: 2
​​​​
rowId: 1
​​​​
sequence: 1
​​​​
<prototype>: {…}
​​​
1: {…}
​​​​
questionId: 13
​​​​
questionLanguages: (4) […]
​​​​
questionType: "MCQ"
​​​​
questionTypeId: 3
​​​​
rowId: 2
​​​​
sequence: 2
​​​​
<prototype>: {…}
​​​
2: {…}
​​​​
questionId: 19
​​​​
questionLanguages: (4) […]
​​​​
questionType: "Likert"
​​​​
questionTypeId: 4
​​​​
rowId: 3
​​​​
sequence: 3
​​​​
<prototype>: {…}
​​​
length: 3
```

Comment: Quick Test shows it's actually working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/7qbftvca/1/ I just removed the `'state' in x && x.state != 3` conditions and changed the comparator `a.sequence - b.sequence` which also works for the 0 case... also added a try..catch for a potential case where the last question is selected... all in all I wouldn't write code like that but it should work. Your problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: @makadev Thanks for help.I have fixed the issue.Deleting the question.